# Is there an instrument that measures temperature (dynamic reading) at high irradiation doses?

Tags: temperature, radiation, instrument

I would like to measure the temperature in industrial gamma irradiation bunker. I know thermocouples are often used, but they only give max temperature reading, and I would like to have a dynamic reading. So far, I haven't been able to find an instrument that would withstand a dose of up to 12 kGy for several hours. Any recommendations or ideas?

Comment: How does a thermocouple "only give max...reading?" A [thermocouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple) has no memory that I know of. It's just two wires that are twisted or welded together. Are you sure that the "max reading" isn't a function of some instrument to which the thermocouple is connected?

Comment: Or, is it possible that "themocouple" means something else in the gamma irradiation business? Some kind of _disposable_ something that undergoes a temperature-dependent state change, and is analyzed after the fact?

Comment: If the temperature is not changing quickly, embedding a thermocouple in a lead ball could work just fine. But, gammas aren't going to do that much to the thermocouple, just keep the meter outside the bunker.